# I'm having trouble with grunt in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, gruntjs

I can't get my terminal to run grunt correctly. I am trying to create a new grunt file and I have already installed grunt. And I don't know why its giving me this error.

```
Last login: Tue Jan  9 19:42:51 on ttys000
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:~ nickcameron$ cd projects
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:projects nickcameron$ cd kittenbook
Nicks-MacBook-Pro:kittenbook nickcameron$ grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
Nicks-MacBook-Pro: kittenbook nickcameron$
```

And this is my Gruntfile.js :

```js
module.export = function (grunt){
    //project configuartion 
    grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
                dest: 'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        }
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
        }
    /*
     * We will configure our tasks here
     */
    });
    // We will load Grunt plugins here
    //Load Grunt plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint'); 
    // We will register tasks here
    //Register tasks 
    grunt.registerTask ('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);
};
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your Gruntfile?

Comment: Ok Chris i added my Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `module.export` is written wrong, the correct one is `module.exports`, also you forgot a comma. Your `gruntfiles.js` should look like this:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt){
    //project configuartion 
    grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
                dest: 'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        }, // <----------------- missing comma here
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
        }
    /*
     * We will configure our tasks here
     */
    });
    // We will load Grunt plugins here
    //Load Grunt plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint'); 
    // We will register tasks here
    //Register tasks 
    grunt.registerTask ('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio, looks like that was part of the problem. I also had to change some of the spacing in my js/values.js and js/prompt.js files. And now its saying this:  Nicks-MacBook-Pro:kittenbook nickcameron$ grunt
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "concat:release" (concat) task
File "release/main.js" created.

Running "copy:release" (copy) task
Copied 1 files                   (***Thanks for your help Fabio***)